# how to use generic IEnumerable Interface in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to setup a class supporting IEnumerable using the Generic version.  Heres my code

```
    internal class Mailboxes : IEnumerable<Mailbox>
    {
        List<Mailbox> MailboxesList = new List<Mailbox>();

        void AddMailbox(Mailbox mailbox)
        {
            return MailboxesList.Add(mailbox);
        }

        public IEnumerator<Mailbox> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return MailboxesList.GetEnumerator();
                }

    }
```

I get this error pointing to the GetEnumerator() line:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0738  'Mailboxes' does not implement interface member 'IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'Mailboxes.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IEnumerator'.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: You need to explicitly implement `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` (due to backwards compatibility with the old non-generic `IEnumerable` interface). I've linked your question to another which shows how to do this

Comment: Since the generic interface inherits the non generic interface: 
`public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable` 
You need to implement the `GetEnumerator` of the non generic interface as well.

Comment: thanks All.  I dont understand why if using Generics is supposed to support type safe code, it forces you do also use a non-generic return too?

Comment: Backwards compatibility. In C# 1 there were no generics, so we just had `IEnumerable`. In C# 2 when generics were added, they made the new generic `IEnumerable<T>` inherit from the old non-generic `IEnumerable`, so that you could write a method which accepted an `IEnumerable<T>` and then pass that to another method which hadn't been updated to use generics and only accepted `IEnumerable`

Comment: OK I see, so just make the non-generic method private.  Thanks again.

Comment: It needs to be public (because interfaces can only be implemented by public methods). It can be *explicit* (and indeed needs to be made explicit, because both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` define a method called `GetEnumerator()`, and you can't define two methods called `GetEnumerator()` with different return types in your class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement non-generic version too (since the [generic one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-7.0) declared as `public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable`), usually it is done via [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

```cs
internal class Mailboxes : IEnumerable<Mailbox>
{
    List<Mailbox> MailboxesList = new List<Mailbox>();

    void AddMailbox(Mailbox mailbox)
    {
        MailboxesList.Add(mailbox);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Mailbox> GetEnumerator() => MailboxesList.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => MailboxesList.GetEnumerator();
}
```